# Not getting DLL_THREAD_DETACH in mixed-mode DLL from managed threads

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI dll that uses thread local storage. It has a `DllMain()` so I can release the TLS when threads exit.

I use this dll from a C# program that creates threads using `System.Threading.Thread`. DllMain() gets `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` calls but never any `DLL_THREAD_DETACH`. If I create threads in the dll itself with `std::thread` then I get the detach calls as expected.

Any ideas why this might be happening, and/or any suggestions for an approach to TLS cleanup?

Comment: If native debugging is enabled, does the debugger report that the threads have exited?  Or might they be kept alive for later reuse?  A possible alternative would be to check for exited threads whenever DllMain is entered (e.g. when another thread is created), you'd need a thread handle to detect thread state, and a mapping from thread ID to the resources, since you would no longer be able to use TLS itself to look up your pointer.

Comment: The threads are exiting normally. I start a new Thread with an empty lambda and Join it. In the debugger I can see the thread come and go.

Comment: The debugger isn't stopping on breakpoints in DllMain when getting a detach call for a thread made in C#. I added a counter for detach calls and it gets incremented properly. So it looks like it's actually working just acting strange in the debugger. Breakpoints in DllMain work fine for other calls. Bizzare.